# How is re-entrancy attack done in case of ERC20 tokens instead of ETH?

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks

I have read through multiple sources about re-entrancy attacks and I understand how the attack is done. But all the examples I found worked on ETH transfer since the attack is through `receive()` function.
But how do people attack a contract in the case of normal ERC20 tokens? We cannot have any `receive()` function in the case of tokens, so what is the way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Note that other blockchains do not suffer from this issue, and it is specific to the archaic design of Ethereum and ERC-20"

Very true. I believe the same applies to BNB blockchain also. BEP-20 & ERC-20 are essentially both archaic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Re-entrancy attacks are possible whenever a smart contract calls an external target, and this is not limited to ETH transfer. It is possible to trigger a re-entrancy attack through executing a method on an external target as well. While most sources might use ETH transfer as an example for simplicity, it is not the only way to trigger a re-entrancy attack.

To provide an example of how a re-entrancy attack can be performed with ERC20 tokens, we can examine the implementation of `swap(..)` in UniswapV2Pool. This method calls an external method `uniswapV2Call` on the external target `to`, as shown in the yellow-highlighted line below:

```
function swap(
      uint amount0Out,
      uint amount1Out,
      address to,
      bytes calldata data
) external lock {
    // code omitted for brevity
    if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (data.length > 0) IUniswapV2Callee(to).uniswapV2Call(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice the presence of the reentrancy guard `lock` that is being utilized in the above code. The `lock` guard prevents re-entrancy attacks by ensuring that only one instance of the method can be executing at any given time. Without this guard, it would be possible to trigger re-entrancy by calling the `swap` method again mid-execution inside the implementation of the external method `uniswapV2Call`.

In summary, while ETH transfer is a common example of a re-entrancy attack, the attack can be triggered through any method that calls an external target. ERC20 tokens are not exempt from re-entrancy attacks, and re-entrancy guards are an essential mechanism to prevent these types of attacks.

Comment: Okay, I get your point. But even if someone triggers the function mid-execution, the block will be mined separately, and the second trigger might give an error while mining. Thus the second trigger will never execute. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @shubhamskatel No, any line interactions till the end of the function call would all be part of the same block and the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> . But how do people attack a contract in the case of normal ERC20 tokens?

ERC-20 `transferFrom()` function can execute arbitrary logic.

There is no "ERC-20 standard", so people rely on an assumed interface that a token looks like ERC-20, whereas the underlying smart contract can be anything.

Note that other blockchains do not suffer from this issue, and it is specific to the archaic design of Ethereum and ERC-20. For example, Solana programs cannot do re-entrancy.